# What's the point of contributing to the camp funds?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I remember early on in the game being told that if I donate money to the camps lockbox, that I can use these funds to improve the camp.
Up until early chapter 3 (where I currently am, so no spoilers please), this is what I did: Taking funds from my personal savings, then upgrading the camp with what I'd just put into the contributions.

However, I just accidentally bought an improvement without actually having the enough in the camp funds and lo and behold, it took what was needed from my wallet as I had more than enough there.
If it can just take funds directly from me, why in the world would I ever want to manually contribute to the camp?

Contributing valuables is nice and convenient, but now I'm wondering what benefit (if any) exists for donating my hard earned cash. I don't see a way to remove cash, so it's not like it's a  safe place to store personal funds...
Plus, if the camp was fully upgraded, couldn't I just accidentally donate too much, leaving extra in the lockbox with no way to get it back (which I haven't quite done yet, so I cannot test.. perhaps you get cut off..)?

Comment: FWIW aside from doing whatever is required for the fast travel, I never bothered my ass contributing and it seemed to make little difference.

Comment: @AlanB - Same. I literally never used anything the camp provided. There wasn't a single point where resources felt scarce and that I needed to dip into the supply at all. The whole impact of having an upgraded camp pretty much seemed pointless by the time I finished (minus fast travel like you said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can increase your honor.

The reason that this helps is self-explanatory. Some people in your gang will be more positive to you, you can get discounts on a lot of restaurants, and you will have a lot of benefits from people (apart from enemy gangs like the O' Driscolls, of course).

In conclusion, it increases your honor, which gives a lot of benefits.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to increasing your honor by donating to camp funds, it is also one of the ways to fence stolen or valuable gear.

While the Fence at Emerald Ranch is unlocked pretty early during the Chapter II quest "The Spines of America". If you have Gold Watches and Silver Belt Buckles you need to offload before completing this quest donating is the only way to do so. Even after unlocking the Fence it may be more convenient to donate to the camp rather than make the trip to Emerald Ranch.

Of course, donating to the camp means the funds can only be used for camp upgrades. Still, I find this to be a good way to boost camp quality immediately after starting the game.